# Button cannot be read in arduino

Tags: button, arduino

I'm using `do while` condition inside arduino's loop.
I put the while condition so it will keep looping inside while, my problem is when i push button its doesn't do anything, I was trying to split this button code and it worked properly, it won;t work if I put in this code.

```
void loop() 
{
  do {
    successRead = getID();
    if (programMode) {
      cycleLeds();              // Program Mode cycles through Red Green Blue waiting to read a new card
    }
    else {
      normalModeOn();     // Normal mode, blue Power LED is on, all others are off
    }
  }

  while (!successRead);
  {   
  buttonState = digitalRead(button); //Read the button --> main problem

  if(buttonState != lastButtonState)
  {
    if(buttonState == LOW){
      buttonPushCounter ++;
      Serial.println("High");
      Serial.print("Number of button pushes : ");
      Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
      }
    else{
      Serial.println("Low");
      Serial.println(buttonPushCounter);
      }
      delay(100);
  }  
  lastButtonState = buttonState;

  if (programMode) {
    if ( buttonPushCounter % 2 == 0 ) { //When in program mode check First If master card scanned again to exit program mode
      Serial.println(F("Master Card Scanned"));
      Serial.println(F("Exiting Program Mode"));
      Serial.println(F("-----------------------------"));
      programMode = false;
      return;
    }
    else {
      if (findID(readCard) ) { // If scanned card is known delete it
        Serial.println(F("I know this PICC, removing..."));
        deleteID(readCard);
        Serial.println("-----------------------------");
        Serial.println(F("Scan a PICC to ADD or REMOVE to EEPROM"));
      }
      else {                    // If scanned card is not known add it
        Serial.println(F("I do not know this PICC, adding..."));
        writeID(readCard);
        Serial.println(F("-----------------------------"));
        Serial.println(F("Scan a PICC to ADD or REMOVE to EEPROM"));
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the capacitor to avoid chatter of a button.[image]